# Open google chrome in full screen

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome, webserver

I want google chrome to start in full screen mode (`f11`) when i start it.

I have done this by adding:  `--kiosk` after the target path.

However when i start up google chrome via the short cut ( The one i just edited) it works.

But when i start it from usb-webserver it does not work.

I think this is becuase it is taking my primary location of google chrome instead of the shortcut.
However i can't edit the primary location of chrome.

How do i start up google chrome in full screen everytime i start it via usb-webserver?

If this is not posible, is it posible to start the page in full screen via `javascript` or `html` or `php`?

**EDIT:**

The page reloads every 3-5 minuts. So i don't want a script, that presses f11 every time the page is loading.
Becuase if that is the case, it will go full-screen - normal - full-screen - normal etc.

**EDIT 2**

Right now my website boots up via index.php

However index.html gets the priority.
So can i make something in index.html that makes the page go full screen. and then auto-redirect to index.php?

Comment: this is not **stackoverflow** question but a **superuser** question and its been [asks](http://superuser.com/questions/614797/can-i-make-google-chrome-allow-fullscreen-by-default)

Comment: The answer given there, is for remove the: You have gone full screen.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP way on a windows machine may be like this. Chrome has to be closed before the start.

```
<?php

$file = fopen("do.bat", "w");

// insert your real chrome path here
fwrite($file, '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk "http://www.reddit.com"' . "\n\r");

fclose($file);
$answer = shell_exec("do.bat");
echo $answer."</br>";
```

Comment: This makes a .bat. However i want to run my Usb-Webserver. And that start up my index.php via google chrome. So basically it's to late then. See edit for my other idea.

Comment: Well on the one hand fullscreen mode in a HTML page with Javascript requires user interaction and can not be launched onLoad and on the other hand chrome has to be closed to start in kiosk mode. You have to change your setting to to get around this.

Comment: The computer that is showing the website, should have 0 user interactions. However kiosk mode works when all the tabs are closed. But when i open usb-webserver, it runs google chrome from the "core" instead of a shortcut. So i don't know how to switch that.

Comment: I do not know your usb-webserver, but I am pretty confident that it just lauches a html page and it gets picked by your default browser. In your case that is chrome. There is no way to change that. If it lauches the page with a command then you can change that easily when you find the code.

Comment: It launches with default browser yes. So i can't change the settings from there :/

Answer (score 0):

Click F11 or run  `chromium-browser --window-size=7000,7000 --start-fullscreen`
in LX.